# how should I apply a formula and get answer in all the odd cells?

Tags: excel

I have number 5 in cell A1. Then the formula **[ Ax+1]** is for column A.

I want to have the result of the formula applied to all odd cells gradually. Can you please help me how I can do this?

Comment: What should happen for even cells? Better still could you paste up the intended results for the first few numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at what OP has not bothered to clarify, maybe, in A3 and copied down:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW()),A1+1,"")
```